# jQuery fadeIn runs twice in its callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var counter = 0;
jQuery("#div1, #div2").fadeIn('300',function(){
{
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
}
```

The code above will print "1" and "2" since the jQuery fadeIn is implied on two different DOM objects.
Is there anyway to cause it to run only once without breaking this code?

Comment: Do you want to have one counter per element ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @dystroy, I need to do some stuff only once in the callback function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a quick solution but not the best

```
var myFlag = true;
jQuery("#div1, #div2").fadeIn('300',function(){
{
    if(myFlag == true)
    {
        // write the code here
        myFlag = false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: This solution might be the best one for me since I'm using jQuery v1.4.2 and can't update it

Answer (score 17):

A simple solution :

```
$("#div1").fadeIn(300);
$("#div2").fadeIn(300,function(){
   // do something only once
});
```

The cleanest solution is to use [jQuery's promise system](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) :

```
$.when($("#div1, #div2").fadeIn('300')).done(function(){
   // do something only once
});
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Uygru/)

Comment: Update jQuery. We're now at version 1.8.

Answer (score 4):

You are explicitly telling it to run twice because you've defined a selector of two items. If you want it to run once, ask it to run on one item:

```
jQuery("#div1")
```

Comment: thanks flem this is the correct answer, for this question: just split them into two sentences:
jQuery("#div1").fadeIn('300');
jQuery("#div2").fadeIn('300',function(){
{
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
})

Answer (score 2):

In terms of sequencing your code:

```
jQuery("#div1, #div2").fadeIn('300',function(){
    counter++;
    console.log(counteR);
});
```

Is the same as

```
jQuery("#div1, #div2").each(function(){
   jQuery(this).fadeIn('300',function(){
        counter++;
        console.log(counteR);
    } );   
})
```

SO your callback will fire for each element

Answer (score 2):

Use the new [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise) in jQuery 1.6, it was made to solve that **multiple callbacks** problem, use it like so:

```
var counter = 0;
jQuery("#div1, #div2").fadeIn('300').promise().done(function()
{
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
});
```